# How to do a 'git log' in the Windows Git Gui?

Tags: git, git-log, git-gui

I just used the Git Gui to clone a local repo from GitHub, and then I checked out a certain branch. I now want to see the equivalent of doing a `git log -50`, but can't seem to find anything in the menu options or on the main screen:

[image]

How can I see the commit history/data for the last, say, 50 changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That GUI isn't just for Windows, it's the standard `git-gui` that ships with Git.

In any case, `git-gui` itself doesn't show log information. It's for creating new commits, managing branches, etc. The companion program [`gitk` visualizes the commit graph](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History#Using-a-GUI-to-Visualize-History) and also contains `git log`-like information.

You can launch `gitk` from `git-gui` using something like **Repository → Visualize master's History** in the menu (or, if you prefer, **Visualize All Branch History**). Alternatively, you can launch it from the command line. I generally want to see all branches, so I use `gitk --all`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are different options (the 3 first ones from command line):

- `gitk`
- or `git-gui`, then *Repository > Visualize master's History*, as mentioned by Chris
- Install Git-webui from https://github.com/alberthier/git-webui and create a script in the PATH to call it quickly. On Windows I created `gitweb.bat` containing:

  ```
  python "D:/Documents/software/____PORTABLE/git-webui-master/release/libexec/git-core/git-webui"
  ```

  [image]
- Use a tool like [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). Note: you have to create an Atlassian or Bitbucket account first even if you want to just use it locally without any repo online (I find this annoying).

  [image]